# Web API routes.IgnoreRoute issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In Web API I have generated html file and saved it in "Exports" directory, now I want user to access this html file through this url:

http://example.com/api/Exports/filename.html

I have used these options but nothing seems to be working:

```
        //1
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Exports/{resource}.html");

        //2
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Exports/{*file}");

        //3
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.html");
```

I am getting this error when I access the Url:

**Message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://example.com/api/Exports/filename.html?callback=1'.",**

**MessageDetail: "No type was found that matches the controller named 'Exports'."**

Comment: Aren't you missing "api" on the beggining?

Comment: IIrc you need to specify the **full** route for the URL, after the domain name. In your case, `api/Exports/{resource}.html`, `api/Exports{*file}` and `api/{file}.html`.